# XOR operator on elements of array

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have the code like this

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A[4] = {3, 519, 27, 49};
    (A[1]) ^=  (A[3]);
    (A[3]) ^=  (A[1]);
    (A[1]) ^=  (A[3]);

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3]);

    A[1] ^= A[3] ^= A[1] ^= A[3];

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3]);
}
```

I want to exchange the value of A[1] and A[3]. For the first printf, I get the answer of 
3, 49, 27, 519, this is right. But for the second, I get 3, 0, 27, 49. 
I think the statement "A[1] ^= A[3] ^= A[1] ^= A[3];" has been translated to:

```
A[1] = A[1] ^ A[3];
A[3] = A[3] ^ A[1] ^ A[3];
A[1] = A[1] ^ A[3] ^ A[1] ^ A[3];
```

and A[1] is always 519, and A[3] equal to 49 when calculating these expression.
when I debug with gdb, I find in this statement A[1] be changed first 49 - > 566 , then A[3] changes from 519 to 49, then A[1] changes from 566 to 0.

I also try to change the declaration like this: volatile int A[4] = {3, 519, 27, 49};
but the output is still all the same.
and change the statement like this: A[1] ^= (A[3] ^= (A[1] ^= A[3]));
the answer is still wrong.

but if i compile the code with g++ instead of gcc, I can get the right answer: 
3, 49, 27, 519
3, 519, 27, 49
and if the statement was

```
int a = 49;
int b = 519;
a ^= b ^= a ^= b;
```

It can exchange the value.
I don't know why it's wrong on the elements of array.

Comment: I think `A[1] ^= A[3] ^= A[1] ^= A[3];` is example of [Undefined_behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C.

Comment: nothing i wrong with your array, your statement is just unsafe since the C specification does not state a necessary operator ordering meaning each compiler implementation is free to provide its own. Hence therefore the statement `A[1] ^= A[3] ^= A[1] ^= A[3];` is a bug since its effect is not predictable from the C language specs alone.

Comment: but why a ^= b ^= a ^= b can get the right answer?

Comment: If you do something undefined, one of things that's allowed to happen is whatever you expected.

Comment: I suggest you forget this XOR swap and use a temporary variable instead. [XOR swap doesn't make much sense with modern compilers and CPUs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have compiled the code with -Wall, but i got nothing. and I think for a ^= b ^= a ^= b, ^= was calculate from right to left, so if i want get the value of the first a, i need calculate the value of the later expression. so i can get the right answer. and for the array one, [] was calculate from left to right, this cause a undefined behavior. am i right?

Comment: @Blastfurnace i just want to know why....

Comment: The other people are correct, `a ^= b ^= a ^= b` is undefined behavior so trying to reason about it isn't a useful activity. The language doesn't specify what the result will be so don't rely on it.

Comment: @Blastfurnace， all right, Thank you for your patience！

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second statement invokes undefined behavior because you're modifying the same value twice between [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

The reason this is undefined behavior is because loose rules like this are necessary if we want the compiler to be able to generate efficient code. In your example it isn't obvious, but if you had a function like this:

```
void
foo(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d)
{
    *a ^= *b ^= *c ^= *d;
}
```

This will be translated in machine code to something like:

```
load r1 (register 1) with value at d
load r2 with value at c
load r3 with value at b
load r4 with value at a
r2 = r1 xor r2
r3 = r2 xor r3
r4 = r3 xor r4
store r2 at c
store r3 at b
store r4 at a
```

But the compiler doesn't know if the pointers point to the same memory or not. So if we want to enforce strict ordering of this function we'd have to do something like this:

```
load r1 with value at d
load r2 with value at c
r2 = r1 xor r2
store r2 at c
load r1 with value at b
r2 = r1 xor r2
store r2 at b
load r1 with value at a
r2 = r1 xor r2
store r2 at a
```

Now, this seems like the same amount of work, doesn't it? The same amount of instructions, just in a different order and as a bonus we're using fewer registers. So why not? The reason is that memory is slow. The first sequence of instructions will execute faster because the cpu doesn't actually wait before the previous instruction is finished before executing the next instruction. You can have dozens of instructions that have started and haven't finished yet. By the time we want the value of r1 in the first example, we've started three more loads from memory. This doesn't sound like much, but things like this add up.

Therefore, the C standard has decided that compilers are allowed to do pretty much what they want between sequence points (I linked a wiki page in the first sentence of this answer that explains what a sequence point is) if they need to do that to generate efficient code. This means that if you want to ensure correct result of your calculations you have to follow certain rules (and the compiler will very often not warn you). You can not modify the same value twice between two sequence points. If you read and modify a value between two sequence points you can only read it to calculate the modification. Etc. There's a bunch of rules about what's undefined and almost all of them are undefined because we want our compilers to be able to generate fast code on a wide range of different CPU architectures.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I think for a ^= b ^= a ^= b, ^= was calculate from right to left, so if i want get the value of the first a, i need calculate the value of the later expression. so i can get the right answer. and for the array one, [] was calculate from left to right, this cause a undefined behavior. am i right?

Comment: @sunshine `a ^= b ^= a ^= b` isn't calculated from any direction to any direction. It's undefined. Whatever code your compiler happened to generate isn't guaranteed to be the same code the compiler generates as soon as you change something else in that function or in the next compiler version or even the next time you compile. Now, if we're talking about how `a ^= b ^= c ^= d` is evaluated, then yes, that's evaluated right-to-left and equivalent to `a ^= (b ^= (c ^= d))`.

Comment: No, I have added the bracket like that into the statement with elements of the array, the output is still wrong.

Comment: Yes, because it's still undefined behavior. You can not modify one value twice between sequence points. I'll expand the answer to maybe give you a hint to why.